# How to remove zero in a string

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

Hi i'm working on c# windows from application and i'm required to remove zero on a string but if the next char is not zero it will stop removing

sample data

```
040079       ->40079
003144       ->3144
440079       ->440079
```

How can I achieve this hope someone help me out

Comment: "040079".TrimStart('0') returns "40079"

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Use the [`TrimStart()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.trimstart?view=netcore-3.1#System_String_TrimStart_System_Char_) overload that accepts a `char` to remove:

```
"040079".TrimStart('0') //"40079"
"003144".TrimStart('0') //"3144"
"440079".TrimStart('0') //"440079"
```